# How do I catch the exception if the user clicks cancel before slecting an image?

Tags: python, tkinter, exception, error-handling

```
    try:
    counter = counter + 1
    second_frame.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select a File", filetypes=(
    ("Image files", ".png",), ("Image files", ".jpg",), ("all files", ".")))


except(OSError,FileNotFoundError):
    print("error")
```

I'm using a file dialogue to import an image file, however, if the user does not select any file I would like to display an error message.

Comment: Try clicking cancel and checking the content of ```second_frame.filename```, is it an empty string?

Comment: @Shar I can tell You that it is `None`, what does that change? I mean it means You can check that `variable is None` and then do sth like `from tkinter.messagebox import showerror; showerror('this is title', 'this is message')` (just split in lines)

Comment: @Matiiss It is empty string if `Cancel` button is clicked.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, you are right, apparently I was testing with `askopenfile()`, well then instead of checking `if variable is None:`, OP can check using: `if not variable:` (or `if variable == '':`) and then: `from tkinter.messagebox import showerror; showerror('this is title', 'this is message')` (just split in lines)